# SQL OpenQuery with Recursive CTE

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-cte

I have the following Recursive CTE which is used in an OpenQuery function in SQL.
I use OpenQuery to query a SQL Linked Server.

(DOES NOT WORK)

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([MyLinkedServerDB], 'WITH SPChainCTE (NAME, INHERIT_FROM) 
AS
(
    Select sp.NAME, sp.INHERIT_FROM from PRODUCT AS sp
    where NAME = ''ProductName''
    UNION ALL
    Select sp.NAME, sp.INHERIT_FROM from PRODUCT AS sp
    INNER JOIN SPChainCTE AS ch on sp.NAME = ch.INHERIT_FROM
)
Select NAME, INHERIT_FROM from SPChainCTE;
');
```

The Above CTE does not work.

However if I execute a non recursive CTE using OpenQuery it works fine.
(This works)

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([FP], 'WITH SPChainCTE (NAME, INHERIT_FROM) 
AS
(
    Select sp.NAME, sp.INHERIT_FROM from ENG.FOCALPOINT.SW_PRODUCT AS sp
    where sp.NAME = ''ProductName''

)
Select NAME, INHERIT_FROM from SPChainCTE;
');
```

Any suggestions? Am I missing something here?

Comment: How is it not working?  BTW, the code sample (curly braces) are your friend...

Comment: Not sure why it is not working. I was wondering if there was any dependency between Open Query and Recursive CTE's.

Comment: Two questions:
1.  Does the recursive CTE work when run directly on the target of [MyLinkedServerDB]?
2.  What differences are there between the linked server targets [MyLinkedServerDB] and [FP]?